# Compilation Failure when compiling class generated by jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have these error when compiling classes generated by JAXB with annotation:

> annotations are not supported in -source 1.3 (use -source 5 or higher
>   to enable annotations) @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
>
> annotations are not supported in -source 1.3 (use -source 5 or higher
>   to enable annotations) @XmlRegistry

...

For all of the annotation.

I have tried with jdk 1.6 or jdk1.7, both lead to the same error.

Any one have seen this before ?

I am using maven-compiler-plugin

> [DEBUG] Trace org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation
>   failure   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)     at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)  at
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375) Caused
>   by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation
>   failure   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
>     ... 17 more

Thank you, 
Khue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Maven compiler plugin tries to compile at the lowest level of Java possible.  So even though you are using Java 6 or 7 it is trying to compile a Java 1.3 application.  You can change it by adding the following to your pom:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```